# band-limited significance of vector length

Tags: matlab

I have a signal which is composed of sum of sinusoidal signals of different frequencies `[1k,2k,3k,4k]Hz` , like below:

```
f = sin(2*pi*1000/fs*n) + sin(2*pi*2000/fs*n) + sin(2*pi*3000/fs*n) + sin(2*pi*4000/fs*n‌​);
```

where `fs=9000` and `n=[1:9000]`.

My first question is in this particular case how to make the signal band-limited and second what is the significance of the length of n.

Comment: you have made a mistake it should be `sin(2*pi*4000/fs*n‌​)` not `sin(2*pi*4000/fsn‌​)`

Answer (score 0):

Bandlimiting means if a signals Fourier transform is zero above a certain frequency thus limiting it, If a signal is sum of sinusoidal signals like in your case the signal is band limited by its highest frequency  which is 4000 Hz in your case, n is the number of samples of your signal if number of samples falls below the Nyquist's frequency which should be at least 2 times the maximum frequency which in your case would be 8000 it will cause [Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). so your sampling frequency or fs should not be less than 8000 which in your case is 9000 which is ok